# Uncaught ReferenceError Class is not define

Tags: javascript

I'm currently creating a game with Javascript and HTML using an MVC design pattern. However, when uploading to the cafe I'm using, I keep getting an error that my View.js class is not being defined in the Controller.js class. However, as by the snippet of code below, you can see that it is:

```
"use strict";

var model = new Model(),
    view = new View(),
    controller = null;

function Controller(){

    this.init = function(){
        view.playGame();
    }
}
```

I also have included the relevant javascript classes within script tags on the single html sheet I'm using. The error message I get in the Chrome debugger is "Uncaught ReferenceError View not defined in Controller.js" Does anybody know why this has started happening? As I have been working on this project for a while and this is the first time it has happened.

Comment: It's happening because the script that defines `View` isn't loading and running successfully, or doesn't define it as a global. You'll want to look in the web console (Ctrl+Shift+I or F12 on most browsers) to see what error is occurring and why.

Comment: You have no class View or Model classes in what you have posted. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: @JGFMK - *"I also have included the relevant javascript classes within script tags on the single html sheet I'm using."* Obviously, it would have been better to show us those, but the claim is they're there.

Comment: Read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, the uncaught referenceerror is what is appearing in the console. I also apologise for not including all of the code, I thought i included the necessary code.

Comment: @JohnSmith - Basically, either: 1) There must be some previous error, or 2) the scripts you're loading don't define a global `View`.